Strange interaction between subfigure and algorithm within minipage
Consider the following code, whose purpose is to place a subfigure and algorithm side by side within a floating figure.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\linewidth}
\caption{subcaption}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[m]{.5\linewidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{alg caption}
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\caption{caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}




The problem is that the main caption shows Figure 2 instead of Figure 1.
The following changes to the above code would produce Figure 1, but none of these solutions are satisfactory.


Get rid of the \begin{algorithm}[H]. Produces Figure 1.
Make subfigure come after the minipage. Produces Figure 1.


Question 1: Why is this problem occuring?
Question 2: Is there a simple solution to have the subfigure (a) on the left, Algorithm 1 on the right, and the main caption showing Figure 1?

subcaption does some juggling with the figure counter and doesn't play well with float.
Hack: step down the figure counter.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\linewidth}
\caption{subcaption}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{alg caption}
\end{algorithm}\addtocounter{figure}{-1}
\end{minipage}
\caption{caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\linewidth}
\caption{subcaption}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{alg caption}
\end{algorithm}\addtocounter{figure}{-1}
\end{minipage}
\caption{caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


I duplicated the figure to ensure that the next figure gets its number right.
